# Code not working. Printing out a few specific elements from a list

Tags: prolog

Task:

pirmieji(S,K,R) R is the first K elements of S

Example:

?- pirmieji([a,b,c,d,e],3,R).

R = [a,b,c].

---

My code:

```
pirmieji(S, K, R) :- pirmiejiRec(S, K, [], R).
pirmiejiRec(_, K, newS, reversedS) :- K == 0, reverseHelp(newS, reversedS), !.
pirmiejiRec([Head|Tail], K, newS, R) :- 0 < K, newK is K - 1, pirmiejiRec(Tail, newK, [Head|newS], R).

reverseHelp([], []).
reverseHelp([X], [X]).
reverseHelp([X|Xs], R) :- reverseHelp(Xs, T), appendHelp(T, [X], R).

appendHelp([],X,X).
appendHelp([H|T], X, [H|S]) :- appendHelp(T, X, S).
```

My code doesn't seem to be working. Would anyone have any idea why?

Maybe you also have other suggestions on how to implement this task?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Variables in prolog always start with capital letters.  Capitalize your variables, `newS`, `reversedS` etc... and see if it works(it should). Learn to use `trace` commands. It help help a lot in debugging recursive predicates and debugging in general.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe you also have other suggestions on how to implement this task?

Use length/2 and append/3.

```
list_prefix(List, Len, Prefix) :-
    length(List, Len),
    append(Prefix, _, List).
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a counter, use succ/2. It does the right thing: it counts down to 0 and after that fails.

```
list_prefix([X|Xs], N, [X|Ys]) :-
    succ(N0, N),
    !,
    list_prefix(Xs, N0, Ys).
list_prefix(_, 0, []).
```

This does not enumerate prefixes of increasing length, like the version with length/2 and append/3.